# Best approaches to use to guess a a string of a certain length under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cryptography

I have been working on a recreational code challenge wherein I need to successfully generate a string of numbers (32 characters in length, numbers 0-9, able to repeat) that matches to a value that is otherwise unknown to me. At first I built a brute force solution, but not only was it basically impossible with something like 10^32 possibilities to make any meaningful guesses, there are time constraints (12 second) and multiple tests to pass within that time span (10 tests with different passcodes each).

Are there specific approaches I can research that might actually be able to solve this problem?

Here was my original bruteforce solution, but I've pretty much discarded the idea of using a brute-force solution:

```js
const carryRemainder = (code, index = 31) => {
  if (code[index] === "9") {
    return index === 0 ? carryRemainder(code, 31) : carryRemainder(code, index - 1);
  }
  
  const newCode = `${code.slice(0, index)}${Number(code[index]) + 1}${"0".repeat(31 - index)}`;
  
  return newCode;
}

function crack(login) {
  let code = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
  
  while (!login(code)) {
    code = carryRemainder(code);
  }
  
  return code;
}
```

Challenge in question:

https://www.codewars.com/kata/59ae7edbba7b60c17500006e/train/javascript

Comment: Are there any constraints or characteristics of the value that is unknown to you? Without more information the best here is just brute-force.

Comment: You could make the `carryRemainder` function more efficient using something like: `(parseInt(code, 10) + 1).toString().padStart(32, '0')`

Comment: @ManishHonnatti I suspect there may be something hidden amongst the challenge description that may help me, I didn't want to link directly to the challenge because my goal was not to just have someone answer the question for me, but if that would give more insight I will.

Comment: @Titus I fear the number of possibilities is so high that no optimization of the brute force will be meaningful.

Comment: @CoryHarper Fair point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brute force is not a viable solution: 10<sup>32</sup> is more than there are atoms in the human body.

One information you could use is this: how much *time* does it take the blackbox verifier to tell you whether the guess was right or wrong?

If that verifier is not so well designed, it could look like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    if (secret[i] != guess[i]) return false;
}
return true;
```

This may look like a very obvious implementation (in that blackbox), but it has a vulnerability: the more characters are correct (as a prefix), the more iterations it will perform. So this gives a hacker some information.

They could time the execution and see if there is on average a tiny tiny longer execution for one particular *first* character. If with many runs it becomes clear that one character stands out, they can assume it is correct, and repeat the same process with the second character, and so on. This is one variant of a [side-channel attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack).

As execution times always have a variable component, due to other things happening on the computer, dynamic execution optimisations (typical for JavaScript engines), garbage collection, ...etc, it is important to run enough samples before jumping to conclusions, but it certainly is the way to do it when the blackbox implementation is designed like above.

Comment: The blackbox is designed similarly, but it uses javascript's `every` array method to perform the same comparison as in your example. How can I time particular iterations without access to the black box?

Comment: You can use the [`performance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now) API. NodeJS also has [process.hrtime](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.8.0/api/all.html#all_process_hrtime). Just take the time *before* the verification call, and then offset it against the time after the call. But with "the call", I really mean 1000s of calls, as otherwise the elapsed time will be too tiny.

Comment: I have a vague memory of seeing this challenge on CodeWars. If you have a reference, I can look up how I solved it.

Comment: https://www.codewars.com/kata/59ae7edbba7b60c17500006e/train/javascript

Comment: The idea of averaging out some function execution times to determine if a piece of the combination is correct sounds like a good idea, I still fear it will time out before I complete the code, but I'll work on implementing that.

Comment: OK, I see I solved that one in the past. I see I actually used `process.hrtime`, and also that I first did a dry run to see how many times I could call the `login` function within 0.01 seconds (passing an empty string), and implemented some double checks to make sure a certain letter really came out as the best choice, ...etc. It was quite a puzzle. Good luck!